# Can I have any way to import module about aws-export.js?

Tags: aws-amplify, es6-modules

Now I'm trying to import aws-exports.js which amplify-js automatically generates in node es6 type code.

my code like this. ex:something.mjs

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

import awsmobile from '../src/aws-exports.js';

something ....
```

and I try to execute under bellow

```
# ./something.mjs

export default awsmobile;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

then, the above error will be output.

I wonder, the aws-exports.js generated by amplify-js is in es6 format, but the extension is js.
Is this the only way to execute it by writing "module" as the "type" field of package.json?

Answer (score 0):

Changing file to .ts worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

deleting the aws-exports.js file and then running "amplify configure project" worked for me